# SSL over Bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, openssl

are there any libraries available, which support secure data exchange using Bluetooth? Theoretically it can be done, by using NDK and OpenSSL for Android, but I'm interested in some ready libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried spongycastle library? (http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/)

Comment: @Analizer Hi, I worked with spongycastle and with bouncycastle as well, but I don't know how this library could help me to make SSL wrapper around BT socket?

Comment: Please clarify what exact stack you mean in the question. Off the top of my head you've got options: `anything/bluetooth-with-encryption`, (should be out of the box), `ssl/network/bluetooth` (out of the box), `ssl/serial/bluetooh` (tricky but can be done), something I didn't think of?

Comment: Did you manage to have it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want ready libraries can be use IOIO Over Bluetooth for Android. if it is using the IOIOLib Application Framework. However, it will need to be re-built against the Bluetooth libraries according to the instructions below link.

Author:

Special thanks go to **Matthias Ringwald**

[IOIO Over Bluetooth](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/IOIO-Over-Bluetooth)